# How to find subscrptionID from within azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service running in microsoft azure.
I want to know if there is any API which can fetch me the subscription id, my app service is running inside.
I know of an API which can be used inside virtual machines which returns metadata including the subscription id.
But i cannot find any relevant API for azure app service.
I don't want to send the subscription from the configuration manually. I suppose there must be a way to fetch is automatically using some API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to obtain the subscription ID from within the app service itself, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEBSITE_OWNER_NAME environment variable:

> Contains the Azure subscription ID that owns the app, the resource group, and the webspace.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#app-environment